# centering an image inside an anchor

Tags: html, css, tags, anchor, centering

I am trying to horizontally center an image that is contained within an anchor tag. I have tried setting it as a block and setting margins to auto with no luck. I have tried wrapping it in a div tag and doing the same, still, no luck. Even tried centering the img within the div within the div. I looked at other posts, and nothing seems to help. The image is still aligned to the left no matter what I do.

###HTML

```
<div id="slideWrapper">
    <h1 id="slideHeading">This is a Header</h1> 
    <hr/>       
    <div class="centerMe">
        <a href="javascript:slidelink()" class="slideA">
            <img src="./images/Slides/cheeseBoards.jpg" name="slide" id="slideImg"/>
        </a>
    </div>
    <hr/>
    <div class="centerMe">
        <a href="javascript:slidelink()"class="slideA" id="slideText">Check out our services and other great stuff.</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

###CSS

```
.centerMe {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border: 1px solid green;
    text-align: center;
}
#slideWrapper {
    border: 1px solid blue; 
}
#slideImg {
    display: block;
    height:500px;
    width:900px;
    border:1px solid red;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

I put borders around everything so that I could see where things were getting placed. It seems like the image isn't being contained within the div for some reason. This seems like it should be so simple. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: i tried your code and its works find in forefox , image is already in center.

Comment: It looks centered to me in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/ymCvt/

Comment: That's really weird. I just tried it firefox and chrome. Its still not centered. It's a php page so I'm running on my computer as localhost on an appache server though xampp. Could that be why it is messed up for me?

Comment: I also have some other css dealing with images as follows
section img
{
display: inline-block;
float: left;
margin:10px;
padding-right:30px;
}
I changed the #slideImg in my original post to img#slideImg but still no dice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure there is no float:left inherited from parents. margin:0 auto; does not work when you have float:left; or position:absolute;

Comment: Thanks for leading me on the right path. I used overflow: auto; and 
width: 100%; within the img#slideImg and it is now centered! Sweet! Still not sure why that makes a difference...

Comment: dude you save my day.